# Javascript jQuery replace a variable with a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of Javascript jQuery code

```
$.post('/blah', { comment_id: 1, description: ... });
```

However, what I really need is the ability to change `comment_id` to something else on the fly, how do I make that into a variable that I can change?

**EDIT**

Clarification, I meant changing the value of `comment_id` to say `photo_id`, so the left side of the assignment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a javascript variable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals

```
 var commentId = 1;
 $.post('/blah', { comment_id: commentId, description: ... });
```

EDIT:

```
var data = {}; // new object
data['some_name'] = 'some value';
data['another_name'] = true;
$.post('/blah', data);  // sends some_name=some value&another_name=true
```

EDIT 2:

```
$.post('/blah', (function () { var data = {}; // new object
  data['some_name'] = 'some value';
  data['another_name'] = true;
  return data;
}()));
```

Comment: Crap, I'm thinking not per this article http://unethicalblogger.com/2008/03/21/javascript-wonks-missing-after-property-id.html

Comment: Yeah, that made it hard to read and simply just moved the code. I'll stick with your first solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
function doIt(commentId) {
  $.post('/blah', { comment_id: commentId, description: ... });
}
```

Thanks to the clarification from Cameron, here's an example that does what the OP actually asked for, that is to make a property name in the object dynamic.

```
function doIt(name, value) {
  var options = {description: '', other_prop: ''};
  // This is the only way to add a dynamic property, can't use the literal
  options[name] = value;
  $.post('/blah', options);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the object to a variable first so that you can manipulate it:

```
var comment_id = 17;
var options =  { description: ... };
options[comment_id] = 1;  // Now options is { 17: 1, description: ... }
```

Comment: This is not what OP asked for, should say `options['comment_id'] = comment_id`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Juan: I thought the OP wanted to change the attribute (not the value), and it turns out I was right (though I agree the question was originally ambiguous)